# Mittag-Leffler Theorem Correction Factor

Tags: complex-analysis, meromorphic-functions

From what I learned and also in [http://math.iisc.ac.in/~vvdatar/courses/2020_Jan/Lecture_Notes/Lecture-17.pdf](http://math.iisc.ac.in/%7Evvdatar/courses/2020_Jan/Lecture_Notes/Lecture-17.pdf), it is said if $\Omega=\mathbb{C}$, then $q_k$ can be polynomial. I wonder how if $\Omega \subsetneq \mathbb{C}$? Can $q_k$ be not a polynomial?

Comment: Yeah, it extends more generally with $q_k$ a polynomial. You'll get uniform convergence on compact subsets of $\mathbb C$.

Comment: @Brevan Ellefsen so for all $\Omega$ we can take $q_k$ to be polynomial? Why is it written if $\Omega=\mathbb{C}$ then $q_k$ is polynomial if it is redundant?

Comment: The author is simply stating the theorem for the easiest case, namely $\mathbb C\setminus K$ where K is a discrete set of points. The case where K is not necessarily discrete (e.g. $K$ compact, $f$ continuous on $K$, and $f$ holomorphic in the interior of $K$) work too, but are more complicated.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen do you have reference for the proof in general case?

Comment: As the PDF you provided mentions, it's essentially an application of the techniques for the $\mathbb C$ case along with an application of Runge's theorem (or more generally Mergelyan's Theorem for the conditions I stated above). I'm not sure of a specific place writing this down explicitly off the top of my head, though I imagine any respectable advanced complex analysis text should prove Runge's theorem (e.g. I know Conway and Rudin do, and I imagine Ahlfors and Narasimhan do) and I wouldn't be surprised if all the details for the lemma you cite are collected in one of those texts.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Great! Thank you so much